# Data not being passed in AJAX get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a simple ajax call. The problem is the data isn't being sent in the parameters. I'm attempting to grab the value that is set in the ahref.

The strange aspect is that if I pass in a hardcoded string, I am able to see that in the parameters. What is wrong with my javascript?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $(".list-group-item").on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();          
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: { 'category': e.target.childNodes[1].data },
                url: "<%= movies_path %>",
                dataType : "script",
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> <%= category.capitalize.humanize %> <span class="badge"><%= Movie.find_category_amount(category) %></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that your AJAX request is passing, debug through your controller action.
If you proceed with AJAX request and your server on terminal catch the debugger you need to trace the functionality and data responding to the request.

Another hint is, I'm not sure if this code could work correctly `url: "<%= movies_path %>",`. I believe you need to pass the full URL to it example: 'movies/index'